# Template specialisation in C++ with const

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm obviously misunderstanding something important about template specialization, because:

```
template<typename type> const type getInfo(int i) { return 0; }
template<> const char* getInfo<char*>(int i) { return nullptr; }
```

fails to compile with:

```
src/main.cpp:19:24: error: no function template matches function
        template specialization 'getInfo'
```

while

```
template<typename type> type getInfo(int i) { return 0; }
template<> char* getInfo<char*>(int i) { return nullptr; }
```

works fine. How do I use `const` with template specializations? What is my rookie mistake?

I am using c++11 on clang++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, in the first example, the return type is `const type`, so the `const` applies to the whole type. If `type` is `char*` (as in your specialisation), then the return type is a `char * const`. This compiles just fine:

```
template<typename type> const type getInfo(int i) { return 0; }
template<> char* const getInfo<char*>(int i) { return nullptr; }
```

This makes sense - if specializing the type as a pointer. Why should the template have any say over what the pointer points to?

However, in this situation, I don't see much reason for having the return type be `const`.

Comment: Thanks. I've got to get const rules cemented sooner or later. The reason for the const return type relates to the original code. The version above was my minimal reproduction of the problem, so yes, it isn't really useful here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to return string constant just use this:

```
template<typename type> type getInfo(int i) { return 0; }
template<> const char* getInfo<const char*>(int i) { return nullptr; }
```

What you tried to do is something like:

```
const int getInfo( int i ) { return 0; }
```

it does not make much sense.

Comment: sftrabbit's answer gave me the epiphany to understand my mistake, but your answer was more what I actually needed, sorry I couldn't accept both!